# Don't download file to memory

Tags: vb.net, stream

i'm working on a conversion from .doc and .docx to html.
this works now like following:

```
Using wc As New Net.WebClient()
    Dim buffer = wc.DownloadData(fileurl)
    Dim stream = new MemoryStream(buffer)
    doc = New Document(stream) ' this is from the conversion library, accepts: fileurl and SysteM.IO.Stream
End Using
```

But when using larger files, this get's all loaded in the memory. And I preferably don't do this.

but I can't seem to find how to read the stream data without loading it all in the memroy. I tried using `wc.OpenRead()` but then I got: `"This stream does not support seek operations."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `WebClient.DownloadFile()` instead.

E.g.

```
Dim filePath As String = "C:\file.doc"

Using wc As New Net.WebClient()
    wc.DownloadFile(fileurl, filePath)
    doc = New Document(filePath)
End Using
```

Comment: method  wc.DownloadData(fileurl, filePath) doesn't exist

Comment: Yep that did the trick, stupid that I didn't see that option. Oh well :) thanks!